# Right Control for Showing Animation?

Tags: qt

I need help on the selecting right control in the QT for animation.

i need to show the animation in my QT application. The animation is in real time. i will get data from my hardware for every 5msec, every 100msec i need to update the animation.

The animation nothing but drawing the line based on the my hardware input, and also i need to implement zooming and Click Event in the animation.

please suggest which is the best control to use this? and please give some rough idea to implement this.

Answer (score 4):

For the graphics part [`QGraphicsView`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsview.html) is the best solution. Have a look at the [graphics view framework overview](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/graphicsview.html) for more information. Animation can be achieved in different ways. Either by redrawing the view every 100 msec, and keep track of the properties of the animating parts yourself, or use the infrastructure provided by [Qt's animation framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/animation-overview.html), which will probably be the easiest approach. In particular, have a look at [`QGraphicsItemAnimation`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsitemanimation.html).